# How can I debug a Maven-built app for IBM WAS using RAD?

Tags: java, maven, websphere, war, rad

I generated a war package using Maven and deployed it in a WebSphere Application Server, but I don't know how to debug it using Rational Application Developer (Eclipse).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run WSAS locally,  you can most likely make RAD launch it in debug mode - read the documentation carefully.

For remote servers, you need to have your instance in debug mode (check the documentation or ask the person responsible for maintaining the server) and then you can do a "Remote Debug" session from RAD.

Comment: For most purposes RAD is just Eclipse with some IBM-specific plugins.  Unless you use  those specific plugins look for Eclipse answers too.